# How to calulate number of days app used?

Tags: android

I have an app in which in have to display from N number of days user using our app. How to achieve this type of scenario?

code:

```
startDateValue = new Date("29/07/2017");
endDateValue = new Date("30/07/2017");
long diff = endDateValue.getTime() - startDateValue.getTime();
long seconds = diff / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
long days = (hours / 24) + 1;
Log.d("days", "" + days);
```

Comment: Every time your app is opened you can add the current date in an Array or a hashset. Before adding you just have to check if it already exists then don't add. Then at the end the count of the array elements is your number of days.

Comment: use sharedpreferences to store `date.getTime()`

Comment: some code snipshot...........

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: I suggest that you turn off your computer and get a paper and pencil. Describe **in words** what steps you need to solve this problem. It will also help to ask yourself some questions. What information do I need to solve the problem? Can I get this information reliably every time the app runs? Or do I need to store any information in between runs?